# Help installing LED tail lights

Tags: jeep, turn-signal, tail-lights

I just ordered LED tail lights for my Jeep (made by KC, not something super sketchy).

I used to have LED turn signals up front (before I realized they looked aweful).  I remember that the LED turn signal unit made them blink at a decent speed, but the turn signal arrows on my Jeep's instrument cluster were always dimly illuminated which is what happens when it thinks your running lights are out.

I was wondering if there's a way to use the new tail light units without load resisters and have both the blink rate and the cluster indicators normal?

Comment: Why do you think the tail lights are going to be any different than the turn signals?

Comment: I know I posted this question a long time ago, but no one actually answered the part about getting rid of the dash cluster lights without using resistors.